# Laravel policy always denies access

Tags: php, laravel, policies

I registered policy

```
protected $policies = [
         'App\Grade' => 'App\Policies\GradesPolicy'

    ];
```

Thi is my route for this resource:

```
Route::get('/grades', 'GradesController@showGrades');
```

Controler method

```
public function showGrades()
    {

        $this->authorize('viewAny');

        switch(Auth::user()->role)
        {
            case 'teacher':
               return view('teacher');
            break;

            case 'parent':
              return view('parent');
            break;

            default:
             abort(400);
            break;
        }
    }
```

And policy method

```
public function viewAny(User $user)
    {

         return $user->check();
    }
```

Yes I know there are related topics here. I read them. I know this is something with model binding. The viewAny method is never invoked. I usedd dd inside of it and it shows nothing. But how am I supposed to bind model here? Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried with `$this->authorize('viewAny', Grade::class);`? Because I think you have to specify the model to let laravel retrive the associated policy

Comment: Thanks man. It works I watched the laracast tutorial but i did not see this approach. I did not see it in any other related topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't specify the relevant model to the authorize method when calling the action "viewAny", so what you need to do is:

```php
$this->authorize('viewAny',Grade::class);
```

or add it directly to the middleware and delete the authorize call from your controller

```php
Route::get('/grades','GradesController@showGrades')
->middleware('can:viewAny,App\Grade');
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunatelly i didn't find it in laracasts tutorial. :/

Comment: You can read more about that in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#via-controller-helpers). It basically says that you have to provide a model instance or the model class to retrieve the correct policy to run